# Closures and dynamic scoping

Tags: lisp, implementation

I'm working on a toy lisp implementation, inspired by [picolisp](http://www.picolisp.com). Thus there are only dynamically scoped variables(plus file local variables). Recently I wondered, whether it is possible to add closures to the language. Currently the bindings of all variables referenced in a lambda expression are stored in the expression's activation record (i.e. on a explicit stack for the lisp implementation) and restored when the execution of that lambda expression is finished. Closures should be possible by saving the bindings of the symbols referenced by the closure, then restore the bindings the closure carries for the duration of the closure's execution and afterwards restoring the previous bindings.

Now to the question: is this equivalent to lexical closures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good simulation of lexical closures depending on what you mean by `saving the bindings...`, it is not quite the same.

```
(defun closure ()
  (let ((var "first value"))
    (format #t "Value is ~a" var)
    (let ((closure (lambda () (format #t "Value inside the closure ~a" var))))
      (setf var "second value")
      (funcall closure))))
```

If you save the value of the binding for the closure, you get the following output:

```
Value is first value
Value inside the closure first value
```

That means that your closure *does not see* the mutation of `var`. Because it only saved the current value when building the closure.

If you save the complete binding (the variable and its value), and all references to this variable uses the same binding (variable and value), then you get lexical closures.

It is not particularly efficient though as there is a lot of copying happening when you invoke a closure.